# Android can't use PrintWriter in other activity

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a client-server app with a java server and the client is an android app.

I create my socket in the android app when the user clicks on a button in a asynktask like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connection);

    TextBienvenue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Bienvenue);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

    if (b != null) {
        juge = (String) b.get("NomJuge");
        TextBienvenue.setText("Bienvenue " + juge);
    }
}

public void send_data(View v) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    String nom = (String) b.get("NomJuge");

    String message = nom + " est connecter";

    MessageSender b1 = new MessageSender();
    b1.execute("connect:" + message);
}

public class MessageSender extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    // Déclaration des sockets pour client
    Handler h = new Handler();
    String reponse;
    String Karateka;
    String[] data;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {
        try {
            String message = voids[0];

            socket = new Socket("10.0.1.90", 8181);

            isReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

            reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);

            while((reponse = reader.readLine()) != null){

                data = reponse.split(":");

                if (data[0].equals("connection"))
                {

                    h.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),data[1],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AttenteKarateka.class);
                            goToNextActivity.putExtra("NomJuge", juge);
                            startActivity(goToNextActivity);
                        }
                    });

                    if (message != null) {
                        writer.write(message + "\n");
                        writer.flush();
                    }
                }

                if (data[0].equals("karateka"))
                {
                    Karateka = data[1];

                    h.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityFormulaire.class);
                            goToNextActivity.putExtra("NomJuge", juge);
                            goToNextActivity.putExtra("NomKarateka",Karateka);
                            startActivity(goToNextActivity);
                        }
                    });

                    //writer.write("test:" + juge + " est pret a envoyer son resultat" + "\n");
                    //writer.flush();
                }
            }

            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
    }
}
```

If the string received from the server starts with "karateka", I go to another activity where there is a form and a button, I want to write to the server from this activity...

```
public class ActivityFormulaire extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Déclaration du textview
    private TextView TextNomJuge;
    private TextView TextNomKarateka;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_formulaire);

        // On assigne la text view de notre activity
        TextNomJuge = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_InputNomJuge);
        TextNomKarateka = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_InputParticipant);

        // On recoit l'intent du changement d'activity
        Intent intent= getIntent();
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

        // Si le bundle recu n'est pas vide on assigne la string a notre textView
        if(b!=null)
        {
            String j =(String) b.get("NomJuge");
            String participant = (String) b.get("NomKarateka");
            TextNomJuge.setText(j);
            TextNomKarateka.setText(participant);
        }
    }

    public class ResultSender extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        // Déclaration des sockets pour client

        Socket socket;
        PrintWriter writer;
        Handler h = new Handler();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {
            try {
                String message = voids[0];
                h.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"resultat envoyer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public void send_result(View v) {
        String message = "resultat: resultat du juge recu du formulaire";
        ResultSender b2 = new ResultSender();
        b2.execute(message);
    }
}
```

I have tried to make my writer Public static in the Activity where I start the socket, and try to use it in the new activity but it doesn't seem to work.

I heard about a singleton to handle my socket but I don't understand how to do it.

Can anyone can help me? It's the last step I need to get working.

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean?

Comment: Well i dont receive anything in the server but if i write in the activity where the socket is started(where the writer is in comment) it worked well

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger to try to tell where it goes wrong?  Are there any errors in the log?  Is it necessary to do this with sockets, or could you use HTTP calls?  That would let you use simpler libraries that take care of the low level stuff for you.

Comment: I cant see no error but can i put my writer public in the doinbackground and write with it in any activity?? Its a good way to do this?

Comment: No, you don't want to be accessing stuff inside an AsyncTask from other activities.  How about a really simple solution of closing the socket and opening it again in the next activity?

Comment: Mmmm i need the socket to stay open because it will continue to send and receive from the server they are on client thread because i can have multiple client, i saw something about a services ill try to do something with this. Thanks a lot for your help nasch! Did you ever use a service to get access to your socket from all activity?

Comment: Never used sockets directly but a service sounds reasonable.